# Changing type of self after call to super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a little trouble with Python's inheritance model. In particular, when calling a method using super(), the method of the super class is invoked, but the self reference type does not change. Hence, calling methods using self will point to the derived class.

I guess it's easier to understand in code:

```py
class A:
    def fun1(self, p1, p2):
        print('A:fun1')
        return f'a: {p1} {p2}'
    def fun2(self, p1):
        print('A:fun2')
        return self.fun1(p1, p1)

class B(A):
    def fun1(self, p1, p2):
        print('B:fun1')
        return super(B, self).fun1(f'b{p1}', f'b{p2}')
    def fun2(self, p1):
        print('B:fun2')
        return super(B, self).fun2(f'b{p1}')

b = B()
print(b.fun1('1', '2'))
print(b.fun2('3'))
```

In the above code we have to functions `fun1` and `fun2`, where one is an 'optimized' version of the other, calling it via `self`. The derived class changes the functionality of both functions but is still based on their super versions.

When executing this, we'll have this output:

```
B:fun1
A:fun1
a: b1 b2
B:fun2
A:fun2
B:fun1
A:fun1
a: bb3 bb3
```

When invoking `B.fun2` using `super()` correctly forwards the call to `A.fun2`. But: the type of `self` does not change and `A.fun2` is now not based on `A.fun1` anymore, but on `B.fun1`, because `self` has type `B`.

I understand why, but is there a way to change this behaviour? I'd really like `self` to always call functions of the 'self' class.

Comment: You only have a single object here, which is both an instance of `B` and of `A`.  You don't have anything that is solely of type `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use `__private` names or store the “base” object in a field instead of subclassing.

Inheritance in python allows classes to override methods of the same name in their base classes. The lookup is done in the [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order).

The only names that do not follow this *shadowing* are names beginning with [two underscores](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private). Python internally rewwrites every attribute lookup on `self` from `__private` to `_ClassName__private`, so that they do not collide with each other.

The other way is to just store your base object in a field — it will then make it impossible to overwrite anything on it. But I think the double underscore way is superior, since it also exposes all the unaltered access to the base object (you can get around it by defining `__getattr__(self, x)` resorting to `getattr(super(), x)` if hiding the base object is desired).

By the way, here you can use `super()` without arguments. This is the simple case described [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#super).